# Checkstyle custom check with gradle (android studio)

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, checkstyle, android-gradle-plugin

I am currently migrating my application project from Ant based Eclipse to Gradle based Android Studio.
My eclipse project has a custom Checkstyle check configured as a custom  and the custom package is then included in the Checkstyle config XML.
I am facing issues migrating this custom check to Android studio. Not sure where how I can indicate gradle to pick up this custom package. 
Stuck at this issue for a couple of days now! Any help is really appreciated...

Currently running into TreeWalker error failing to instantiate the custom package:

**[Error]**

```
Unable to create a Checker: cannot initialize module TreeWalker - Unable to instantiate jp.myproject.tools.checkstyle.checks.naming.MemberNameCheck
```

**[checkstyle-packages.xml]**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE checkstyle-packages PUBLIC
"-//Puppy Crawl//DTD Package Names 1.0//EN"
"http://www.puppycrawl.com/dtds/packages_1_0.dtd">

<checkstyle-packages>
  <package name="jp.myproject.tools.checkstyle.checks.naming" />
</checkstyle-packages>
```

**[Checkstyle config file]**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Puppy Crawl//DTD Check Configuration 1.3//EN" "http://www.puppycrawl.com/dtds/configuration_1_3.dtd">

<!--
    This configuration file was written by the eclipse-cs plugin configuration editor
-->
<!--
    Checkstyle-Configuration: myproject android checks
    Description: none
-->
<module name="Checker">
  <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
  <property name="charset" value="UTF-8" />
  <module name="TreeWalker">
    <property name="tabWidth" value="4"/>
    <module name="FileContentsHolder"/>
    <module name="CyclomaticComplexity">
      <property name="severity" value="info"/>
      <property name="max" value="15"/>
    </module>
    <module name="NPathComplexity">
      <property name="severity" value="info"/>
      <property name="max" value="200"/>
    </module>
    <module name="JavadocMethod">
      <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
      <metadata name="net.sf.eclipsecs.core.lastEnabledSeverity" value="inherit"/>
    </module>
    <module name="JavadocType">
      <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
      <metadata name="net.sf.eclipsecs.core.lastEnabledSeverity" value="inherit"/>
    </module>
    <module name="JavadocVariable">
      <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
      <metadata name="net.sf.eclipsecs.core.lastEnabledSeverity" value="inherit"/>
    </module>
    <module name="JavadocStyle">
      <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
      <property name="endOfSentenceFormat" value="([。.?!][ \t\n\r\f&lt;])|([。.?!]$)"/>
      <metadata name="net.sf.eclipsecs.core.lastEnabledSeverity" value="inherit"/>
    </module>
    <module name="AbstractClassName">
      <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
      <metadata name="net.sf.eclipsecs.core.lastEnabledSeverity" value="inherit"/>
    </module>
    <module name="ClassTypeParameterName">
        <property name="format" value="^[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*$"/>
    </module>
    <module name="ConstantName">
      <property name="format" value="^[A-Z_][A-Z0-9_]*(_[A-Z0-9]+)*$"/>
    </module>
    <module name="LocalFinalVariableName"/>
    <module name="LocalVariableName"/>
    <module name="MemberName">
      <property name="applyToProtected" value="false"/>
      <property name="applyToPackage" value="false"/>
      <property name="applyToPrivate" value="false"/>
      <property name="format" value="^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$"/>
    </module>
    <module name="jp.myproject.tools.checkstyle.checks.naming.MemberNameCheck">
      <property name="applyToPublic" value="false"/>
      <property name="applyToNestedClassMember" value="false"/>
      <property name="format" value="^m[A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]+$"/>
    </module>
    <module name="MethodName"/>
    <module name="MethodTypeParameterName"/>
    <module name="PackageName"/>
    <module name="ParameterName"/>
    <module name="StaticVariableName"/>
    <module name="TypeName"/>
    <module name="AvoidStarImport">
      <metadata name="net.sf.eclipsecs.core.lastEnabledSeverity" value="inherit"/>
    </module>
    <module name="IllegalImport">
      <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
      <metadata name="net.sf.eclipsecs.core.lastEnabledSeverity" value="inherit"/>
    </module>
    <module name="RedundantImport">
      <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
      <metadata name="net.sf.eclipsecs.core.lastEnabledSeverity" value="inherit"/>
    </module>
    <module name="UnusedImports">
      <property name="processJavadoc" value="true"/>
      <metadata name="net.sf.eclipsecs.core.lastEnabledSeverity" value="inherit"/>
    </module>
    <module name="LineLength">
      <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
      <property name="max" value="100"/>
      <property name="tabWidth" value="4"/>
      <metadata name="net.sf.eclipsecs.core.lastEnabledSeverity" value="inherit"/>
    </module>
    <module name="MethodLength">
      <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
      <metadata name="net.sf.eclipsecs.core.lastEnabledSeverity" value="inherit"/>
    </module>
    <module name="ParameterNumber">
      <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
      <metadata name="net.sf.eclipsecs.core.lastEnabledSeverity" value="inherit"/>
    </module>
    <module name="EmptyForIteratorPad">
      <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
      <metadata name="net.sf.eclipsecs.core.lastEnabledSeverity" value="inherit"/>
    </module>
    <module name="GenericWhitespace">
      <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
      <metadata name="net.sf.eclipsecs.core.lastEnabledSeverity" value="inherit"/>
    </module>
    <module name="MethodParamPad">
      <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
      <metadata name="net.sf.eclipsecs.core.lastEnabledSeverity" value="inherit"/>
    </module>
    <module name="NoWhitespaceAfter">
      <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
      <metadata name="net.sf.eclipsecs.core.lastEnabledSeverity" value="inherit"/>
    </module>
    <module name="NoWhitespaceBefore">
      <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
      <metadata name="net.sf.eclipsecs.core.lastEnabledSeverity" value="inherit"/>
    </module>
    <module name="OperatorWrap">
      <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
      <metadata name="net.sf.eclipsecs.core.lastEnabledSeverity" value="inherit"/>
    </module>
    <module name="ParenPad">
      <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
      <metadata name="net.sf.eclipsecs.core.lastEnabledSeverity" value="inherit"/>
    </module>
    <module name="TypecastParenPad">
      <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
      <metadata name="net.sf.eclipsecs.core.lastEnabledSeverity" value="inherit"/>
    </module>
    <module name="WhitespaceAfter">
      <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
      <metadata name="net.sf.eclipsecs.core.lastEnabledSeverity" value="inherit"/>
    </module>
    <module name="WhitespaceAround">
      <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
      <metadata name="net.sf.eclipsecs.core.lastEnabledSeverity" value="inherit"/>
    </module>
    <module name="ModifierOrder">
      <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
      <metadata name="net.sf.eclipsecs.core.lastEnabledSeverity" value="inherit"/>
    </module>
    <module name="RedundantModifier">
      <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
      <metadata name="net.sf.eclipsecs.core.lastEnabledSeverity" value="inherit"/>
    </module>
    <module name="AvoidNestedBlocks">
      <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
      <metadata name="net.sf.eclipsecs.core.lastEnabledSeverity" value="inherit"/>
    </module>
    <module name="EmptyBlock">
      <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
      <metadata name="net.sf.eclipsecs.core.lastEnabledSeverity" value="inherit"/>
    </module>
    <module name="LeftCurly">
      <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
      <metadata name="net.sf.eclipsecs.core.lastEnabledSeverity" value="inherit"/>
    </module>
    <module name="NeedBraces">
      <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
      <metadata name="net.sf.eclipsecs.core.lastEnabledSeverity" value="inherit"/>
    </module>
    <module name="RightCurly">
      <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
      <metadata name="net.sf.eclipsecs.core.lastEnabledSeverity" value="inherit"/>
    </module>
    <module name="DoubleCheckedLocking">
      <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
      <metadata name="net.sf.eclipsecs.core.lastEnabledSeverity" value="inherit"/>
    </module>
    <module name="EmptyStatement">
      <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
      <metadata name="net.sf.eclipsecs.core.lastEnabledSeverity" value="inherit"/>
    </module>
    <module name="EqualsHashCode">
      <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
      <metadata name="net.sf.eclipsecs.core.lastEnabledSeverity" value="inherit"/>
    </module>
    <module name="HiddenField">
      <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
      <metadata name="net.sf.eclipsecs.core.lastEnabledSeverity" value="inherit"/>
    </module>
    <module name="IllegalInstantiation">
      <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
      <metadata name="net.sf.eclipsecs.core.lastEnabledSeverity" value="inherit"/>
    </module>
    <module name="InnerAssignment">
      <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
      <metadata name="net.sf.eclipsecs.core.lastEnabledSeverity" value="inherit"/>
    </module>
    <module name="MagicNumber">
      <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
      <metadata name="net.sf.eclipsecs.core.lastEnabledSeverity" value="inherit"/>
    </module>
    <module name="MissingSwitchDefault">
      <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
      <metadata name="net.sf.eclipsecs.core.lastEnabledSeverity" value="inherit"/>
    </module>
    <module name="RedundantThrows">
      <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
      <metadata name="net.sf.eclipsecs.core.lastEnabledSeverity" value="inherit"/>
    </module>
    <module name="SimplifyBooleanExpression">
      <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
      <metadata name="net.sf.eclipsecs.core.lastEnabledSeverity" value="inherit"/>
    </module>
    <module name="SimplifyBooleanReturn">
      <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
      <metadata name="net.sf.eclipsecs.core.lastEnabledSeverity" value="inherit"/>
    </module>
    <module name="DesignForExtension">
      <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
      <metadata name="net.sf.eclipsecs.core.lastEnabledSeverity" value="inherit"/>
    </module>
    <module name="FinalClass">
      <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
      <metadata name="net.sf.eclipsecs.core.lastEnabledSeverity" value="inherit"/>
    </module>
    <module name="HideUtilityClassConstructor">
      <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
      <metadata name="net.sf.eclipsecs.core.lastEnabledSeverity" value="inherit"/>
    </module>
    <module name="InterfaceIsType">
      <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
      <metadata name="net.sf.eclipsecs.core.lastEnabledSeverity" value="inherit"/>
    </module>
    <module name="VisibilityModifier">
      <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
      <metadata name="net.sf.eclipsecs.core.lastEnabledSeverity" value="inherit"/>
    </module>
    <module name="ArrayTypeStyle">
      <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
      <metadata name="net.sf.eclipsecs.core.lastEnabledSeverity" value="inherit"/>
    </module>
    <module name="FinalParameters">
      <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
      <metadata name="net.sf.eclipsecs.core.lastEnabledSeverity" value="inherit"/>
    </module>
    <module name="TodoComment">
      <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
      <metadata name="net.sf.eclipsecs.core.lastEnabledSeverity" value="inherit"/>
    </module>
    <module name="UpperEll">
      <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
      <metadata name="net.sf.eclipsecs.core.lastEnabledSeverity" value="inherit"/>
    </module>
    <module name="AnnotationUseStyle">
      <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
      <metadata name="net.sf.eclipsecs.core.lastEnabledSeverity" value="inherit"/>
    </module>
    <module name="MissingDeprecated">
      <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
      <metadata name="net.sf.eclipsecs.core.lastEnabledSeverity" value="inherit"/>
    </module>
    <module name="MissingOverride">
      <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
      <metadata name="net.sf.eclipsecs.core.lastEnabledSeverity" value="inherit"/>
    </module>
    <module name="PackageAnnotation">
      <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
      <metadata name="net.sf.eclipsecs.core.lastEnabledSeverity" value="inherit"/>
    </module>
    <module name="SuppressWarnings">
      <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
      <metadata name="net.sf.eclipsecs.core.lastEnabledSeverity" value="inherit"/>
    </module>
    <module name="StringLiteralEquality">
      <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
      <metadata name="net.sf.eclipsecs.core.lastEnabledSeverity" value="inherit"/>
    </module>
    <module name="ArrayTrailingComma">
      <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
      <metadata name="net.sf.eclipsecs.core.lastEnabledSeverity" value="inherit"/>
    </module>
    <module name="UnnecessaryParentheses">
      <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
      <metadata name="net.sf.eclipsecs.core.lastEnabledSeverity" value="inherit"/>
    </module>
    <module name="OneStatementPerLine">
      <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
      <metadata name="net.sf.eclipsecs.core.lastEnabledSeverity" value="inherit"/>
    </module>
    <module name="ParameterAssignment">
      <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
      <metadata name="net.sf.eclipsecs.core.lastEnabledSeverity" value="inherit"/>
    </module>
    <module name="PackageDeclaration">
      <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
      <metadata name="net.sf.eclipsecs.core.lastEnabledSeverity" value="inherit"/>
    </module>
    <module name="NoFinalizer">
      <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
      <metadata name="net.sf.eclipsecs.core.lastEnabledSeverity" value="inherit"/>
    </module>
    <module name="NestedTryDepth">
      <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
      <metadata name="net.sf.eclipsecs.core.lastEnabledSeverity" value="inherit"/>
    </module>
    <module name="DefaultComesLast">
      <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
      <metadata name="net.sf.eclipsecs.core.lastEnabledSeverity" value="inherit"/>
    </module>
    <module name="GenericWhitespace">
      <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
      <metadata name="net.sf.eclipsecs.core.lastEnabledSeverity" value="inherit"/>
    </module>
    <module name="EmptyForInitializerPad">
      <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
      <metadata name="net.sf.eclipsecs.core.lastEnabledSeverity" value="inherit"/>
    </module>
    <module name="DeclarationOrder">
      <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
      <metadata name="net.sf.eclipsecs.core.lastEnabledSeverity" value="inherit"/>
    </module>
  </module>
  <module name="NewlineAtEndOfFile">
    <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
    <metadata name="net.sf.eclipsecs.core.lastEnabledSeverity" value="inherit"/>
  </module>
  <module name="Translation">
    <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
    <metadata name="net.sf.eclipsecs.core.lastEnabledSeverity" value="inherit"/>
  </module>
  <module name="FileLength">
    <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
    <metadata name="net.sf.eclipsecs.core.lastEnabledSeverity" value="inherit"/>
  </module>
  <module name="FileTabCharacter"/>
  <module name="JavadocPackage">
    <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
    <metadata name="net.sf.eclipsecs.core.lastEnabledSeverity" value="inherit"/>
  </module>
  <module name="RegexpSingleline">
    <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
    <property name="format" value="\s+$"/>
    <property name="message" value="Line has trailing spaces."/>
    <metadata name="net.sf.eclipsecs.core.lastEnabledSeverity" value="inherit"/>
  </module>
  <module name="SuppressionCommentFilter"/>
  <module name="SuppressWithNearbyCommentFilter">
    <property name="commentFormat" value="CHECKSTYLE IGNORE THIS LINE"/>
    <property name="checkFormat" value=".*"/>
    <property name="influenceFormat" value="0"/>
  </module>
  <module name="StrictDuplicateCode">
      <property name="severity" value="info"/>
  </module>
</module>
```

Comment: What is your `build.gradle`? You can get an idea how to run checkstyle from this project: https://github.com/stephanenicolas/Quality-Tools-for-Android/blob/master/build.gradle

Comment: Well checkstyle as such works fine without the custom checkstyle package. I've configured checkstyle based on this project [https://github.com/marcoRS/volley-examples]. The error occurs when I try to add the custom checkstyle package

Comment: Which Checkstyle version did you use with ant? Because `-n packageNamesFile` option has been dropped for Checkstyle 5.0. Gradle plugin is using Checkstyle 5.6. You should place `checkstyle-packages.xml` at the root of your jar with custom checks as documentation says: http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config.html#Packages or update checkstyle config file to use full package name for custom checks.

Comment: the Checkstyle version with ant was 5.5. Yes the packageNamesFile option was dropped in 5.0, so I've been using the full package name in the checkstyle config file and copying checkstyle-packages.xml to build/ directory during ant compile target. but i am not sure how to do this for gradle so that it recognizes my custom Checkstyle package

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this? i have the exact same issue

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using the standard gradle checkstyle plugin you should only need to add

```
dependencies {
  checkstyle 'custom:checkstyle:0.01' //Replace this with a dependency on your custom checkstyle code.
}
```

Which will extend the classpath of the checkstyle plugin to include your extra package.

If you don't have an internal maven/ivy repo to pull your code from you'll probably need to look through the [dependency documentation](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html) at how to specify file or project dependencies.

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't work for me! I tried quite a few patterns to add dependencies like "checkstyle fileTree(dir:'src' , include:'*.java')" etc but it gradle doesn't recognize the custom Check
}

Comment: Adding source files to your classpath won't do anything useful. You'll need the compiled code on checkstyle's classpath.
If your checkstyle extensions are also in the same source tree you should be able to add `tasks.withType(Checkstyle) { checkstyleClasspath += checkstyleMain.classpath}` to your build file  and remove the previous suggestion of adding a dependencies block.
This will add the code from main source set to the checkstyles runtime classpath.